# Application center management console is not reachable

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I am having a problem accessing my the Application Center management console. I have installed it as part of IBM Worklight 6.1.0.1.

When I visit `http://<hostname>:port/appcenterconsole/console.html`, I am able to access it using `demo/demo`.

If I do this from inside the firewalls, everything is working as expected. When I try to access the same from outside the firewall, I experience some problems. The logging appears to be fine at first, but when I get to the page it says `unknown user` in the upper right corner. Also, at the top where the applications are supposed to be listed, I see a red box saying `Application Center Server is not reachable`.

The same happens with http://:/appcenterconsole/installers.html - I see an empty list, with an error saying `Can't get the installer list`.

I do figure that this probably is firewall related, but I am not able to find out what needs to be opened, that is not open now.

Any pointers in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the Application Center to work when behind a firewall you need to configure the service endpoint so that the console can call the rest services when the console is open from outside the firewall.

In particular the JNDI property ibm.appcenter.services.endpoint must be set as the external address and context root of the applicationcenter.war web application.

You can look at https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/r_ac_appres_endpoint.html  for details on this configuration.

Hope this helps.
Emmanuel